# How to map a native query, that has more columns than a table?

Tags: java, hibernate, xml-configuration

I have a class with 4 fields, a table with 2 columns and a native query, that return 4 columns.
let's say:
a class:

```
class Foo{
    int id;
    String name;
    int stat;
    String statName;
}
```

a table:

```
foo
---------
id | name
```

and mapping:

```
<class name="Foo" table="foo">
    <id name=id/>
    <property name="name"/>
    <property name="stat"/>
    <property name="statName"/>
</class>
<sql-query name="getWithStat">
    <return class="Foo"/>
    <!--stat and statName calculated as aggregation and concatenation from other table-->
</sql-query>
```

But with this mapping, I can't use basic entity, because table hasn't columns for `stat` and `statName`. How shoul I map this extra fields from my query into my class?

Comment: Is stat and statName field from other entity classes?

Comment: @PoojaAggarwal no, it's calculated in query (some concatenation and aggregation of fields from other table).

Answer (score 1):

```
you can use Transient annotation of JPA to ignore property at time of persist.

class Foo{
    int id;
    String name;
    @Transient
    int stat;
    @Transient
    String statName;
}
```

Comment: But it is **not** transient, I want result from my query to be mapped there. However, I don't want this properties to be mapped when persisting or getting an entity from the table (because they are **not** exist there)